# Hot to make UIAlert with data from UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertview

I have converter application with `tableView` with cells which contains results of conversion.

For example you entered 5 kilometers and in `tableView` cells for Meters shows 5000 and so on.

I want to make `UIAlert` with full result when press to one of cells.
So i want to se my result for Meters and i press on meters cell. How could i make it?

I tried to make a additional variables and connect them to Alert but the value still shows not the cell that i choose but the first cell at the table that shows at the moment...

Does anyone have ideas?

---

```
let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCell") as! ResultTableViewCell

let item = converter[indexPath.row]
cell1.nameResult.text = item.title
cell1.subtitleResult.text = item.subtitle

//MARK: - Форматтер для результатов
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = maxdigits



if converterVal == NSLocalizedString("Километр", comment: "") {

    cell1.labelResult.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: inputValue).multiplying(by: NSDecimalNumber(value: item.kfKilometer)))
    resultVar = cell1.labelResult.text!
    resultName = cell1.nameResult.text!

    return cell1

} else if converterVal == NSLocalizedString("Метр", comment: "") {

    cell1.labelResult.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: inputValue).multiplying(by: NSDecimalNumber(value: item.kfMeter)))
    resultVar = cell1.labelResult.text!
    resultName = cell1.nameResult.text!

    return cell1

} else {

    cell1.labelResult.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: 0))
    return cell1        
}
```

---

`nameResult` - is name of converted value
and `labelResult` - is result of conversion
and for every cell i have `if else` statement.

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tableView == self.tableView2 {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("\(inputValue) \(detailLabel) is:", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("\(resultVar) \(resultName)", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .alert)


        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Спасибо", comment: ""), style: .default) { action in
            // ...
        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
            // ...
        }
    }

//    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

---

And i want to show more closely this labels in Alert but only for every cell it must be own...

Comment: add your code ? without code we can't help you

Comment: Added tableView :cellForRowAt: part

Comment: where is the code that present alert ?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati it’s simple alert with title and message and name result and label result

Comment: have you implement `didSelectRowAt` delegate method of `uitableview`?

Comment: Alert inside :didSelecrRowAt: function

Comment: show `didSelectRowAt`  code, may be you something missing in it

Comment: Added code for did select row

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to modify you method like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tableView == self.tableView2 {
       // get your selected row data 

        let item = converter[indexPath.row]
         //use item.title or item.subtitle instead of label

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("\(inputValue) \(detailLabel) is:", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("\(resultVar) \(resultName)", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .alert)


    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Спасибо", comment: ""), style: .default) { action in
        // ...
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
        // ...
    }
    }

}
```

Let me explain something : `cellForRowAt indexPath` this method create cell and fill data whatever you pass in it. so if you assign value `resultVar` in this method, it will give you wrong value.

`didSelectRowAt` called when you click on cell row, so assign value `resultVar` in this method and do your operations or whatever you want

Access cell instead when you click on row

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCellClass {
     // access your cell label and get values
     print(cell.titleLable.text!)

}
```

Comment: Wow! It works but resultVar (number value in string type still showing for other cell

Comment: with 'item.title' i've done, but how i assign value from result label in cell to var? Because i have a lot if else statements for different conversion units

Comment: add if else conditions in `didSelectRowAt` function like you added in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: i tried but it’s not working coz there is if else statement for cells and cellforrowat

Comment: where you assign `resultVar ` and `resultName` values? don't tell in `cellForRowAt`, its wrong

Comment: hmm... but how I could get this values if I have a structure for every value and in :cellForRowAt: it check statement for chosen basic value and begin to convert input value multiplying it on coefficients of different values for this concrete value. Like if I convert kilometres it will be multiple input value on 1000 for meters, 100000 santimeters and so on... ?